# Terminal is losing the blink and is not showing text after using (batcat)

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, text, cursor, syntax-highlighting

So, I used `batcat` to syntax highlight a file in the terminal. After I close it through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, my cursor stops blinking and I cant see the text I type in my terminal.

[Error](https://github.com/JothaM123/errorinlinux/raw/main/error.mp4)

Comment: Killing `batcat` prevents it resetting the default terminal state, which it changes so it can do the fancy formatting. Just run the command `reset` in the terminal (it should work even if you can't see it being typed). [You probably don't want to be in Kali if you are not familiar with basic commands like this.]

Comment: Contact batcat's developers, ask them to gracefully handle Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `reset` command as @Paul_Pedant said, the terminal will get reset and the "blink" will be restored.